# A word to describe the feeling of the lump in the throat due to nostalgia

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the feeling of the lump in the throat due to nostalgia? If so, what is it?

Comment: Do you want to know what the sensation of feeling a lump feels like?

Comment: You've got the flu.

Comment: I think nostalgia or nostalgic is the word for that feeling under that circumstance (positively reminiscent).

Comment: There is a difference between a "lump in the throat due to nostalgia" and a "lump in the throat, e.g., due to nostalgia."

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's very common, but I've heard people use the word **verklempt** to describe this feeling.

> Verklempt is a Yiddish word that means "overcome with emotion." Pronounced "fer-klempt," people use it when they are so emotional that they're on the verge of tears or at a loss for words due to their emotional state.

(from http://judaism.about.com/od/glossary/g/Definition-Of-Verklempt-Yiddish-Word.htm)

Comment: +1 A very handy addition to anyone's vocabulary, esp., the emotional types.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there's a single word, but people often say...

> [I was choked up](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I%20was%20choked%20up%22&oq=%22I%20was%20choked%20up%22&gs_l=serp.3...7790.9351.10.9716.7.7.0.0.0.0.139.594.5j2.7.0...0.0...1c.1.nECKWV3kQuk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.d2k&fp=cc60941f39a1f1cf&bpcl=39967673&biw=1271&bih=829) or [felt choked up](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20choked%20up%22&oq=%22felt%20choked%20up%22&gs_l=serp.3...137076.139162.11.139713.9.9.0.0.0.0.75.534.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.nZcnxu8YdEw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.d2k&fp=cc60941f39a1f1cf&bpcl=39967673&biw=1271&bih=829)

...in situations where they're [overcome by emotion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22overcome%20by%20emotion%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) like this.

Comment: I was pondering *choked* but wasn't sure whether it applied specifically to *nostalgia*. I thought choked was any emotion.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I could be wrong, but I'd be *very* surprised if English had different words depending on whether the "lump in the throat" is caused by nostalgia, pity, penitence, etc. It might even be just a Pavlovian response to a Hollywood [melodrama/weepie](http://www.filmsite.org/melodramafilms.html) - they're all physically pretty much the same reaction, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this progression is universal, but a particular experience could induce a  *[pang](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pang)* of nostalgia, which, in turn could cause a person's throat muscles to clench up and create that "lump" sensation you are describing.

In terms of how to describe that feeling in the throat, calling it a "lump" *is* the word commonly used to describe the sensation. If you want a verb, I would suggest *[clench](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clench).*

Comment: I don't think I've ever come across *clench* used in the context of extreme emotions - except *clenched teeth* (anger), and *buttock-clenching* (fear/embarrassment).

Comment: clenched teeth, clenched buttocks, clenched throat: aren't they all the result of high emotion?

Comment: Of course - but as I say, in my experience, *clench* only turns up in the context of emotions like *anger/fear/embarrassment*, not *nostalgia*.

Answer (score 1):

The lump is the feeling one gets just before crying which can be caused by many different emotions, including the [blank] of nostalgia.

(here's the fun part!):

The ***warm glow***  of nostalgia

The ***unsettling guilt*** of nostalgia

The ***sharp longing*** of nostalgia

The ***wispy rememberences*** of nostalgia

Comment: I think we're getting into the realms of "creative writing" here. Granted, the "warm glow of nostalgia" is fairly commonplace - a cliche, even. But there's not a single instance of any of the other three in Google Books (or indeed, *"wispy **rememberances***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, granted, my ***examples*** may be unique but I was giving the OP another way to show the emotion of nostalgia (thus causing a lump in the throat) instead of telling about a lump in the throat which is actually a reaction to an emotion.

Comment: Well yes, but an *answer* shouldn't stray too far from the actual question - which in this case requests *a word to describe the feeling of the lump in the throat...*. Not that I think there is one, but we should probably at least stick to terms relating to physical/bodily reactions, rather than other associated mental/abstract constructs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, of course.  Stretching the boundaries? Probably.  Adding some insight instead of just filling a blank?  Definitely.  ;-)

Comment: As you say yourself - *"here's the fun part!"* I guess we'd none of us be here if it wasn't "fun" in some way. But I will be interested to see if someone comes up with a form of words specifically and only describing the physical reaction OP's asking about.

Answer (score 1):

[Globus](http://www.royalberkshire.nhs.uk/pdf/Globus_dec10.pdf) ( *-pharyngis*)

> ***a feeling of a lump in the throat***
>   Globus is the medical term for a sensation of a lump in the throat where no true lump
>   exists. It was once called Globus Hystericus, wrongly suggesting that this is a psychiatric
>   condition. Globus is sometimes also referred to as Globus pharyngeus (pharyngeus is
>   simply the medical term for the throat).

Wikipedia entry for [Globus pharyngis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globus_hystericus) includes psychosomatic factors to Globus:

> In some cases the cause is unknown and symptoms may be attributed to a **psychogenic cause** i.e. a somatoform or **anxiety disorder**. It has been recognised as a symptom of **depression**, which responds to anti-depressive treatment. [emphasis mine]